# Your PHP installation appears to be missing MYSQL extension which is required by wordpress for redhat

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have been struggling with this error for quite sometimes and I am wondering if someone could help me get this running

I have

```
php -v 7.2.24
mysql -v 8.0.21
Apache 2.4.37
redhat 8.4
```

it keeps giving me the same error, I have removed and reinstalled php or mysql but didnt solve the issue. I also found other posts and i let the php.ini to have `extension=mysqli` still the same error.

I tried to have a index.php to the DNS and it shows that there is not any mysql section

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you need to install the MySQL extension for PHP:

```
# yum install php-mysql
```

Then restart Apache

```
# service httpd restart
```